# Akka with SBT and IntelliJ

Tags: scala, sbt, akka

Has anyone had any luck getting Akka to load with SBT within IntelliJ? Everything else with SBT has worked great.  I, for whatever reason, can't seem to get it to pull in the akka libraries with it. It looks like it is resolving the typesafe akka libraries, but doesn't seem to show any of the libaries in the External libraries

IntelliJ Version: 14.0.3

****EDIT****

SBT Config:

```
name := "MessageProcessor"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.10.4"

resolvers += "Typesafe Repository" at "http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/"

libraryDependencies += "org.scalatest" % "scalatest_2.10" % "2.0" % "test"

//https://github.com/nscala-time/nscala-time
libraryDependencies += "com.github.nscala-time" %% "nscala-time" % "1.8.0"

libraryDependencies += "io.spray" %%  "spray-json" % "1.3.1"

libraryDependencies +=  "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-actor" % "2.4-SNAPSHOT"
```

Any ideas would be very much appreciated. Good chance I am overlooking something obvious.

SBT Entry:

```
libraryDependencies +=  "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-actor" % "2.4-SNAPSHOT"
```

Comment: have you tried https://github.com/mpeltonen/sbt-idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was finally able to actually get it to work.  I had to get the info from mvnrepository.com instead of from the akka site.

```
libraryDependencies += "com.typesafe.akka" % "akka-actor_2.11" % "2.3.9"
```

http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.typesafe.akka/akka-actor_2.11/2.3.9

--s

Comment: If you are using scala 2.10 but include a library of akka from 2.11, there might be potential problems. And I see there's 2.3.9 version of 2.10 in maven repo, which you could still use `"com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-actor" % "2.3.9".

Answer (score 1):

So what's your `scala` version? I think you should change your `akka` version to adapt the `scala` version and also you can try don't use the `SNAPSHOT` version.

Comment: Thanks @chengpohi I supplied my SBT config above with Scala Version. I did try targeting 2.39 instead of the 2.4-SNAPSHOT, but didnt' seem to make any difference.

Comment: Maybe you can try upgrade your scala version to `2.11.3`, also you need to upgrade your `scalatest` version to ` "org.scalatest" % "scalatest_2.11" % "2.2.1" % "test",`

Answer (score 0):

For the Akka 2.4-SNAPSHOT, you will need to add `resolvers += "Akka Snapshots" at "http://repo.akka.io/snapshots/"`